# Define $\rho(f,g):=\int \frac{|f-g|}{1+|f+g|}d\mu.$. Show that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure $\Longrightarrow$ $\rho(f_{n},f)\rightarrow 0$.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$  be a measurable space, suppose $\mu(X)<\infty$. If $f$ and $g$  measurable functions on $X$, define 
$$\rho(f,g):=\int \frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|}d\mu.$$

Let $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable function. Show that $\rho(f_{n},f)\rightarrow 0$ iff  $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure.

**My problem:** Show that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure $\Longrightarrow$ $\rho(f_{n},f)\rightarrow 0$.

**My attempt:** Since $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure, then, in particular, for each $\varepsilon>0$ we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu\left(\left\{x\in X \: \left|\: |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{\varepsilon}{2\mu(X)}\right.   \right\}\right). $$

Therefore, there exists $N$ such that if $n\geq N$ then
$$\mu\left(\left\{x\in X \: \left|\: |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{\varepsilon}{2\mu(X)}\right.   \right\}\right)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{1}$$
We called 
$$E_{\varepsilon}^{n}:=\left\{x\in X \: \left|\: |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2\mu(X)}\right.   \right\}.$$
Then we have
$$\mu(E_{\varepsilon}^{n})<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{2}$$
Note that
$$\frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|}< \frac{\varepsilon}{2\mu(X)} \qquad \mbox{in }X\setminus E_{\varepsilon}^{n}.  $$

So, as $\frac{|fn-f|}{1+|f_{n}-f|}\leq 1$ we have
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\rho(f_{n},f) &=& \int \frac{|f_{n}-f|}{1+|f_{n}-f|}d\mu \\
&=&{\displaystyle \int_{X\setminus E_{\varepsilon}^{n}} \frac{|f_{n}-f|}{1+|f_{n}-f|}d\mu+\int_{E_{\varepsilon}^{n}} \frac{|f_{n}-f|}{1+|f_{n}-f|}d\mu  } \\
&\leq& {\displaystyle  \frac{\varepsilon}{2\mu(X)}\int_{X\setminus E_{\varepsilon}^{n}}d\mu + \int_{ E_{\varepsilon}^{n}} d\mu   } \\
&=& {\displaystyle  \frac{\varepsilon}{2\mu(X)} \mu(X\setminus E_{\varepsilon}^{n}) +\mu( E_{\varepsilon}^{n})   } \\
&\leq& {\displaystyle  \frac{\varepsilon}{2\mu(X)} \mu(X) +\mu( E_{\varepsilon}^{n})   }  \\
&<& {\displaystyle  \frac{\varepsilon}{2}  + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}   }  \\
&=& \varepsilon.
\end{array}  
$$

**My Question:**  Is there any error in my attempt?

The doubt is born because in this [link](https://www.math.brown.edu/~rkenyon/teaching/2009/2210/Set3.pdf) (see pag 5) makes an impractical proof and this is the only demonstration I found on the internet.

Comment: Your proof seems good. To be nitpicking, your $\rho$ should be $$ \rho(f, g) = \int \frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|} \, d\mu $$